# SELECT part of string between symbol and space

Tags: string, select

I need to create a subquery (or view) column with values pulled from part of a long string.  Values will appear like this:

"Recruiter: *Recruiter Name* Date:..."

I need to select the recruiter name after : and end with the space after the recruiter name.  I understand that normalizing would be better, but we only have query access not database setup access in this case.

Ideas appreciated!

Comment: I should be more specific.  I'm using MS SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex for this. A regex will let you express that you want to search for the text *Recruiter* followed by a colon, a space, and a series of characters followed by a space, and that you want it to extract those characters.

The expression might look a bit like this (untested)

```
Recruiter: (.+) Date:
```

This would look for 'Recruiter: ' literally, followed by a string of any characters (`.`) of length 1 or larger (`+`), which is to be extracted (the brackets), followed by the literal string ' Date:'.

How you use this with SQL depends on your vendor.

Comment: Thanks - what is the syntax for using the above within a SELECT statement?

Comment: I think that depends on exactly what database package you're using. A quick Google search for your database and "regex" should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that pulls out the value for a given key. You would use it like:

```
        select [dbo].[GetValue]('recruiter', 
                             'aKey: the a value Recruiter: James Bond cKey: the c value')
```

This returns 'James Bond'

Here is the function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create function [dbo].[GetValue](@Key varchar(50), @Line varchar(max))
   returns varchar(max)
as
begin

declare @posStart int, @posEnd int

select @posStart=charindex(@Key, @Line)  -- the start of the key
if(@posStart = 0)
    return ''    -- key not found

set @posStart = @posStart + len(@Key) + 1  -- the start of the value
select @line = substring(@line, @posStart, 1000) -- start @Line at the value

select @posEnd=charindex(':', @line) -- find the next key
if(@posEnd > 0)
begin
    -- shorten @line to next ":"
    select @line = substring(@line, 0, @posEnd)

    -- take off everything after the value
    select @posEnd = charindex(' ', reverse(@line));
    if(@posEnd > 0)
        select @line = substring(@line, 0, len(@line) -  @posEnd + 1)

end

return rtrim(ltrim(@line))

end
go
```